# Selection of multiple values from drop down list

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, drop-down-menu

I've a drop down list that contains all the ontacts on mobile. I want to select more than one contact at a time.

When I was working on regular html & JS pages I used this code:

```
     function loopSelected()
     {
      var txtSelectedValuesObj = document.getElementById('txtContactsName');
      var selectedArray = new Array();
      var selObj = document.getElementById('AllContacts');
      var i;
      var count = 0;
      for (i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) 
      {
         if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
         selectedArray[count] = selObj.options[i].value;
        count++;
       }
     }
     txtSelectedValuesObj.value = selectedArray;
  }
```

But when I use it on Android, then `if statement` is skipped & it just stops,this statement:

```
    "selObj.options[i].selected"
```

seems strange for the mobile!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked:

```
    function ChooseContact(data)
    {
      var txtSelectedValuesObj = document.getElementById('txtContactsName');
      var selectedArray = new Array();
      var selObj = document.getElementById('contacts');
      var i;
      var count = 0;
      for(i=0;i<selObj.options.length;i++)
      {
        if(selObj.options[i].selected==true)
        {
         selectedArray[count] = selObj.options[i].value;
         alert(selObj.options[i].value);
         count++;
        }
      }
     txtSelectedValuesObj.value = selectedArray;
   }
```

I just modified this:

```
    if (selObj.options[i].selected)
```

to this:

```
   if(selObj.options[i].selected==true)
```